# Is there a name for a layout containing a list and detailed view of currently selected list item?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, interaction-design, layout, design-patterns

Like in an attached screenshot - on the left there is a list of all orders and on the right detailed view of a invoice of a selected order. 
 Is there a name for such a layout / UX workflow?

[image: Layout containing a list and detailed view of currently selected list item]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's referred to as a '[**Master details pattern**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/master-details)'.

The right pane can also be referred to as an inspector panel, or property sheet, although normally those are usually a narrow, scrollable stacked form.